# thread_cond_signal() was not declared in the scope

Tags: c++, multithreading, compilation, g++

I'm trying to compile a program using thread_cond_signal ()

My imports are

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>


#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>

#include "parser.h"
#include "safe_queue.h"
#include "priqueue.h"
#include "base64.h"
#include "xmlhelper.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "messagehelper.h"
#include "default_config.h"
#include "main_process_helper.h"
#include "ExcludesParameters.h"
#include "eErrors.h"
#include "s_Error.h"
#include "eMessage_Type.h"
#include "hmaps.h"
#include "cookiestatus.h"
#include "sha1.h"
#include "ExcludeFields.h"
#include "pthreadStruct.h"
```

and my compile batch script is

```
g++ -g -lpthread utils/hregex.cpp ExcludeFields.cpp utils/sha1.cpp utils/utils.cpp utils/base64.cpp utils/xmlhelper.cpp utils/messagehelper.cpp utils/safe_queue.cpp utils/parser.cpp utils/default_config.cpp ExcludesParameters.cpp main_process_helper.cpp main.cpp -Iutils -Ibusiness_objects -o telepath_sniff
```

the output:

```
‘thread_cond_signal’ was not declared in this scope
```

the code is:

```
thread_cond_signal( &cond_garbageQueue);
```

any idea of what else I should add? It does compile on Eclipse

Thanks

Comment: So what's the error you get ?

Comment: edited..hope the details suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean pthread_cond_signal()?

Comment: Yes sorry I will edit it

Comment: I mean, could that be the problem? Because otherwise, I don't know -- you just need to #include <pthread.h> and compile with -pthread/-lpthread.

Comment: Sorry ales_t I usually never misspell names wrong so I didn't even think about checking it out . Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

pthread_cond_signal(&cond) should only need -lpthread for linking.
Can you give some more details on the error?